# Deciding between Probit and Multi-nominal Probit if one of three categories is very unlikely? Proving randomness of that category?

Tags: multinomial-distribution, probit, categorical-data, multinomial-logit, multinomial-probit

I have a choice variable, which is either A or B or C. But apparently C is hardly chosen. And for me it seems like it more "happens to be chosen". 
I want to estimate which some continuous covariates, whether or not number A or B is chosen. But the mere presence of "choice alternative" C (even if it has only very few observations) should force me to use a multinominal model (probit or logit).

Is there a way I can justify to drop alternative C and use probit (or logit) with alternative A or B?

Is there a way to test the assumption, that alternative C is chosen at random.

Content wise: A or B are Yes or No in a vote and C is either abstain or just not present, but the alternatives within C cannot be determined.